# Refreshing values from a File to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, file-io, arraylist, jtable

I'm trying to refresh values in a `JTable` from a file so that I can display them in the table. I have a model, but I don't know why it's not working. I've tried pretty much everything that i could think of. Here is the code for the GUI and the `TableModel`:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.getStateChange()== ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
            outputFile.filename= "C:\\File Database\\"+Dropdown.getSelectedItem();
            outputFile.ReadData();

            int count=0;
            System.out.println("Array list size:" +outputFile.filedata.size());
            for(int i=0; i< datafield1.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j< datafield1.getColumnCount(); j++)
                {
                    fval= outputFile.filedata.get(count); 
                    count++; 
                    datafield1.setValueAt(fval,i,j);
                }
            }
        }
```

Table model:

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class PreviousDataRefresh extends AbstractTableModel  
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    float[][] rowData = new float[15][11]; 

    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
        return 11;
    }

    public int getRowCount() 
    {
        return 15;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
    {
        return null;
    }
     public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
     {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
     }
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) 
    {
        rowData[row][col] = (Float) value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

}
```

The `ArrayList` works because every time I select a new file from the `ComboBox` I see the float values change, but I can't see them being inputted into the table.

Comment: I have doubt about your loop in 'itemStateChange()' method

Comment: Have you tried `yourTableVariable.revalidate()` in `setValueAt`? Maybe it's just not rebuilding the layout or repainting.

Comment: `public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) 
 {
  rowData[row][col] = (Float) value;
  guitable.datafield1.revalidate();
  //this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
  
 }`
I made the edit but it overloaded the stack.... i also tried to implement tableChanged but i don't know what it does to actually grab the data and put in on the table. @TeamIncredible what kind or doubt do you have i might be able to do something about it

Comment: Have a look at my updated code, i changed the `JFileChooser` to a `JComboBox` to select the files.

Answer (score 0):

Hej UP2ME4ME,

i made a very small and simple example `JPanel` for you, which contains a `JTable` and a `JButton` to load the other `File`.

So here is the code of the updated JPanel with a JComboBox, to select a file

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import swingdemoapp.table.model.LoadDataFromFileModel;
import swingdemoapp.table.model.MyComboBoxModel;

public class LoadDataFromFilePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JTable myTable;
    private LoadDataFromFileModel model;
    private JButton loadNewFile;
    private JComboBox selectFile;
    private MyComboBoxModel boxModel;
    private JFileChooser chooser;

    private final String USER_HOME  = System.getProperty("user.home");

    public LoadDataFromFilePanel(final File file) {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));


        File[] files = new File[1];
        files[0] = new File("resources/file1.dat");

        selectFile = new JComboBox(files);
        selectFile.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(selectFile, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        model = new LoadDataFromFileModel(file);
        myTable = new JTable(model);

        this.add(myTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(loadNewFile)) {
            chooser = new JFileChooser(new File(USER_HOME));
            int showOpenDialog = chooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
            if(showOpenDialog == 0) {
                File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                model.updateTableData(selectedFile);
            }
        }

        if(e.getSource().equals(selectFile)) {
            File selectedFile = (File) selectFile.getSelectedItem();
            model.updateTableData(selectedFile);
        }
    }
}
```

The TableModel, it contains a class, which is the domain class for my data from the files

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Patrick Ott <Patrick.Ott@professional-webworkx.de>
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class LoadDataFromFileModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private final String[] columnNames = {"Firstname", "Lastname", "City"};
    private List<DataFromFile> data;

    public LoadDataFromFileModel(final File file) {
        data = readFile(file);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        DataFromFile value = data.get(rowIndex);
        switch(columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return value.getFirstName();
            case 1:
                return value.getLastName();
            case 2:
                return value.getCity();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private List<DataFromFile> readFile(final File file) {
        List<DataFromFile> data = new ArrayList<>();
        if(!file.isDirectory() && file.canRead()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader(file));
                String line = "";

                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] split = line.split(",");
                    DataFromFile dff = new DataFromFile(split[0], split[1], split[2]);
                    data.add(dff);
                }
                System.out.println("Reading from file finished");
                br.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LoadDataFromFileModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LoadDataFromFileModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, i can not read your input file!");
        }

        return data;
    }

    public void updateTableData(final File file) {
        data = readFile(file);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}


class DataFromFile {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String city;

    public DataFromFile(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String city) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.city = city;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Here is one Text File, i read Firstname, Lastname and Cityname from this file, which are separated by one Tab, at which i split the `String` later in the `readFile` Method.

Hans,Mayer,New York
Carl,Louis,California
Maria,Sharapova,Miami

I hope it will help you and you can adapt it for your App.

Patrick

Comment: Thanks so much Patrick... hopefully this helps my data is all floats by the way with comma delimitation but the concept is here for sure. i'm not using JFileChooser because i have a parent file defined everywhere so i use JComboBox instead i can give you the code to look at if you want along with a data file, is that ok?

Comment: @UP2ME4ME yes, please edit your question and add your code there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the code un-touched before i started to do anything, i know it's a little unclean but it's because i'm rushing to finish this project... really sorry

Main GUI class: 
Variables:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
float fval=0; 
XBee xbee = new XBee();
XBeeResponse response; 
JFrame MainFrame;
JTextField OnOff;
JTable datafield0, datafield1;
JComboBox<String> Dropdown; 
Filer outputFile = new Filer(); 
XBeeDecoder decode = new XBeeDecoder();
CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
String[] FileNames = new File("C:/File Database/").list(); 
Queue<XBeeResponse> ConvertingQueue = new LinkedList<XBeeResponse>();
Queue<XBeeResponse> Rqueue = new LinkedList<XBeeResponse>(); 
DecimalFormat formatfloat = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
JButton XBee, Data, Graph, Pdata;
```

Previous Data Panel:

```
public void MakePreviousDataPanel()
    {
        PdataBack.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        Dropdown = new JComboBox<String>(FileNames);
        Dropdown.addItemListener(this);
        gbc.gridy=0; 
        gbc.ipady=15;
        gbc.ipadx=30; 
        PdataBack.add(Dropdown,gbc);
        gbc.gridy=1;
        gbc.ipady=20; 
        PdataBack.add(CreateLabel("Accel X       Accel Y       Accel Z       Gyro X       Gryo Y       Gryo Z       Temp       Air Pressure       Alititude       Latitude       Longitude"), gbc);
        datafield1= new JTable(15,11);
        datafield1.setAutoscrolls(true);
        datafield1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        datafield1.setDragEnabled(true);
        datapanel1.setSize(700,500); 
        datapanel1.add(datafield1);
        gbc.gridy=2; 
        gbc.ipady=25;
        gbc.gridheight=1; 
        PdataBack.add(datafield1, gbc);
        gbc.gridy=3; 
        gbc.gridheight=1;
        gbc.ipady=10; 
        PdataBack.add(backbutton,gbc);
    }
```

ActionPerformed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    { 
            if(event.getSource() == XBee)
            {
                if(xbee.isConnected()==true)
                {
                    OpenCloseXBee(0);
                    OnOff.setText("XBee is Off");
                }
                else
                {
                    OpenCloseXBee(1);
                    OnOff.setText("XBee is On");
                }
            }
            if(event.getSource() == Data)
            {
                card.show(MainBack, "Data");
                //System.out.println("Values in queue: "+ ConvertingQueue.size());
                outputFile.responses.addAll(ConvertingQueue);   
                System.out.println("Responses in queue: "+ Rqueue.size());
                outputFile.filecounter= new File("C:/File Database/").listFiles().length;
                outputFile.filecounter++;
                outputFile.filename="C:/File Database/data"+outputFile.filecounter+".txt";
                outputFile.CreateFile();
                outputFile.ConvertToFloat();
                outputFile.WriteHeader();
                outputFile.WriteData();

                if(xbee.isConnected() == false)
                {
                    if(ConvertingQueue.isEmpty()==false)
                    {
                        for(int i=0; i< datafield0.getRowCount(); i++)
                        {
                            for(int j=0; j< datafield0.getColumnCount(); j++)
                            {
                                fval= decode.processfloat(ConvertingQueue.poll());
                                formatfloat.format(fval); 
                                datafield0.setValueAt(fval,i,j);
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
            if(event.getSource() == Graph)
            {
                card.show(MainBack, "GraphBack");
            }
            if(event.getSource() == Pdata)
            {
                card.show(MainBack, "Previous Data");
            }
            if(event.getSource()==choose)
            {
                int showOpenDialog = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(getParent());
                if(showOpenDialog == 0) {
                    File selectedFile = chooseFile.getSelectedFile();
                    model.updateTableData(selectedFile);
                }
            }
            if(event.getSource()==back)
            {
                card.show(MainBack, "Main");
            }
        }
```

Last but not Least the filer class:

```
package com.rapplogic.xbee.examples.wpan;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.rapplogic.xbee.api.*;


public class Filer 
{
    //Use PrintWriter to Open/Close File and use FileWriter to write/read to file
    String filename; 
    int filecounter;
    Queue<XBeeResponse> responses = new LinkedList<XBeeResponse>();
    LinkedList<Float> fvals = new LinkedList<Float>(); 
    ArrayList<Float> filedata = new ArrayList<Float>();
    DataOutputStream RunOutput;
    FileOutputStream Filewrite; 
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    XBeeDecoder decode = new XBeeDecoder(); 
    File fileread; 
    Scanner Reader; 

    public Filer()
    {
        //filename = "C:/File Database/data"+filecounter;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException //Main Method Close the file here after operations finish 
    { 
        //Test Block DO NOT USE test block to only be used with file data0 
        Filer data = new Filer();
        data.filename= "C:/File Database/data12.txt";
        data.ReadData(); 
        //data.CreateFile(); 
        //data.WriteHeader();
        //data.WriteData();
        //data.RunOutput.close();

    }
    public void CreateFile()
    {
        try 
        {  
            this.Filewrite = new FileOutputStream(this.filename, false);
            this.RunOutput = new DataOutputStream(Filewrite); 
            System.out.println("File Created"); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("File Not Opened/Not Created");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
    public void ConvertToFloat()
    {       
        float fval=0;
        int size=responses.size(); 
        for(int i=0; i< size; i++)
        {
            fval= decode.processfloat(responses.poll());
            fvals.add(fval); 
        }
    }

    public void WriteData()
    {
        String fString=null; 
        try
        {
            while(fvals.isEmpty()==false)
            {
                if(fvals.peek() !=555)
                {
                    fString= Float.toString(fvals.poll());  
                    RunOutput.writeBytes(fString+",");
                }
                else
                {
                    RunOutput.writeBytes(newline);
                    fvals.remove(); 
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not written to"); 
        }       
        System.out.println("Wrote data to file");
    }

    public void WriteHeader()
    {
        try 
        {
            RunOutput.writeBytes("Accel X,Accel Y,Accel Z,Gyro X,Gryo Y,Gryo Z,Temp,Air Pressure,Alititude,Latitude,Longitude");
            RunOutput.writeBytes(newline);  
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
    public void ReadData()
    {
        fileread = new File(filename);
        System.out.println(this.filename); 
        try 
        {       
            Reader = new Scanner(fileread);
            Reader.nextLine();
            String text=""; 
            while(Reader.hasNext())
            {
                text+= Reader.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println(text); 
            String[] collected = text.split(",");    
            for(int temp=0; temp<collected.length; temp++)
            {
                this.filedata.add(Float.parseFloat(collected[temp]));
                //System.out.println(temp); 
            }
            System.out.println("Filer Array list size:" + this.filedata.size());
            /*for(int temp=0; temp< filedata.size(); temp++)
                System.out.println(filedata.get(temp)); */
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException num)
        {
            System.out.println("No Numbers found/ Cannot format values");
        }

    }
    public List<Collection> ReadData(final File file) {
        List<Collection> data = new ArrayList<>();
        if(!file.isDirectory() && file.canRead()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                br.readLine(); 
                String line = "";
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] split = line.split(",");
                    Collection dff = new Collection(Float.parseFloat(split[0]),Float.parseFloat(split[1]),Float.parseFloat(split[2]),Float.parseFloat(split[3]),Float.parseFloat(split[4]),Float.parseFloat(split[5]),
                                                    Float.parseFloat(split[6]),Float.parseFloat(split[7]),Float.parseFloat(split[8]),Float.parseFloat(split[9]),Float.parseFloat(split[10]));
                    data.add(dff);
                }
                System.out.println("Reading from file finished");
                br.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PreviousTableModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PreviousTableModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, i can not read your input file!");
        }

        return data;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public List<Collection> SortData(ArrayList<Float> RawData)
    {
        List<Collection> sortedData = null; 
        while(RawData.isEmpty() ==false)
        {
            Collection fullCollect =new Collection(RawData.get(0),RawData.get(1),RawData.get(2),RawData.get(3),RawData.get(4),RawData.get(5),
                                    RawData.get(6),RawData.get(7),RawData.get(8),RawData.get(9),RawData.get(10));
            for(int i=0; i<11;i++)
                RawData.remove(0); 
            sortedData.add(fullCollect); 
        }
        return sortedData;

    }

    public class Collection 
    {
        float AccelX,AccelY,AccelZ,GyroX,GyroY,GyroZ,
              Temp,AirPressure,Altitude,Latitude,Longitude;

        public Collection( final float AccelX, final float AccelY, final float AccelZ, final float GyroX, final float GyroY, 
                            final float GyroZ, final float Temp, final float AirPressure, final float Altitude, final float Latitude, final float Longitude)
        {
            this.AccelX= AccelX; 
            this.AccelY=AccelY; 
            this.AccelZ=AccelZ; 
            this.AirPressure= AirPressure; 
            this.Altitude=Altitude;
            this.GyroX=GyroX;
            this.GyroY=GyroY; 
            this.GyroZ=GyroZ; 
            this.Latitude=Latitude; 
            this.Longitude=Longitude; 
            this.Temp=Temp; 
        }

        public float getAccelX() {
            return AccelX;
        }

        public void setAccelX(float accelX) {
            AccelX = accelX;
        }

        public float getAccelY() {
            return AccelY;
        }

        public void setAccelY(float accelY) {
            AccelY = accelY;
        }

        public float getAccelZ() {
            return AccelZ;
        }

        public void setAccelZ(float accelZ) {
            AccelZ = accelZ;
        }

        public float getGyroX() {
            return GyroX;
        }

        public void setGyroX(float gyroX) {
            GyroX = gyroX;
        }

        public float getGyroY() {
            return GyroY;
        }

        public void setGyroY(float gyroY) {
            GyroY = gyroY;
        }

        public float getGyroZ() {
            return GyroZ;
        }

        public void setGyroZ(float gyroZ) {
            GyroZ = gyroZ;
        }

        public float getTemp() {
            return Temp;
        }

        public void setTemp(float temp) {
            Temp = temp;
        }

        public float getAirPressure() {
            return AirPressure;
        }

        public void setAirPressure(float airPressure) {
            AirPressure = airPressure;
        }

        public float getAltitude() {
            return Altitude;
        }

        public void setAltitude(float altitude) {
            Altitude = altitude;
        }

        public float getLatitude() {
            return Latitude;
        }

        public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
            Latitude = latitude;
        }

        public float getLongitude() {
            return Longitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
            Longitude = longitude;
        }


    }
}
```

Table Model:

```
package com.rapplogic.xbee.examples.wpan;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import com.rapplogic.xbee.examples.wpan.Filer.Collection;

public class PreviousTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String[] columnNames={"AccelX", "AccelY","AccelZ","GyroX","GyroY","GryoZ","Temp","Air Pressure","Altitude","Latitude","Longitude"};
Filer tableFile = new Filer(); 
List<Collection> allCollections;

public PreviousTableModel()
{

}
@Override
public int getColumnCount() 
{
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() 
{
    return allCollections.size(); 
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Collection value = allCollections.get(rowIndex);
    switch(columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return value.getAccelX();
        case 1:
            return value.getAccelY();
        case 2:
            return value.getAccelZ();
        case 3:
            return value.getGyroX();
        case 4:
            return value.getGyroY();
        case 5:
            return value.getGyroZ(); 
        case 6:
            return value.getTemp();
        case 7:
            return value.getAirPressure();
        case 8:
            return value.getAltitude(); 
        case 9:
            return value.getLatitude();
        case 10:
            return value.getLongitude();
    }

    return null;
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
}

public void updateTableData(File selectedFile) { 
    allCollections = tableFile.ReadData(selectedFile);
    System.out.println("Changing table");
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

}

So this is all the code that i have prior to making any table models or any significant changes... again i really appreciate you help patrick i'll attempt to make a inner class to store all the data in and see if that works thanks again and sorry for the messy code :)

Comment: Hey @Patrick i was able to create a table model that uses the JFileChooser the file works as well as the Collection class that i made to make objects from the data but from some reason it's still not updating... the updated code is above